# How to get a particular table in content control c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk, contentcontrol

I have 3 tables inside the same content control, how to I get the first table and delete it?

I've tried using

```
SdtBlock ccWithTable = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                    (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tag).Single();

Table theTable = ccWithTable.Descendants<Table>().First();

ccWithTable.RemoveChild(theTable);
```

But this is giving me an error:

> The specified oldChild is not a child of this element

I am suspecting that because the table isn't a child of the content control, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @Nahuell The specified oldChild is not a child of this element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, I guess you are able to access the `table` object but it's not direct child ot the `sdtblock`, so you can't remove it with `ccWithTable.RemoveChild()` method (yes, it supposes the item to remove is part of direct children of this element).

But if you can access the table object (that is a sub chilld), no need to know its parent.
Just call the `OpenXmlElement.Remove()` method: it will remove the element from its parent.

```
theTable.Remove();
```

Comment: By any chance do you know how to clear the content of a table row in theTable object?

Comment: @yzwboy Never tried, and not sure about what you mean by "clear the content". In any case it would another question ;)